# Displaying kmean result with specific colors to specific clusters

Tags: matlab, k-means

I applied k-mean clustering on a preprocessed image using the following matlab code

```
%B - input image
C=rgb2gray(B);
[idx centroids]=kmeans(double(C(:)),4);
imseg = zeros(size(C,1),size(C,2));
for i=1:max(idx)
     imseg(idx==i)=i;
end
i=mat2gray(imseg);
% i - output image
```

Every time I display the output, color assigned to the output images changes.
How can I give a specific color to cluster1, cluster2, cluster3 and cluster4.

Comment: you can do it in the line you display the output, unfortunately you havent added it to the code so we cant help...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a colormap. Let `R1`, `B1` and `G1` be the RGB values you want to dispaly the first cluster in (values in range [0..1]), and `R2` be the red channel value for the second cluster and so on... Then your color map is:

```
cmp = [R1 G1 B1;
       ...
       R4 G4 B4];
```

Now,

```
[idx centroids] = kmeans(double(C(:)),4);
imseg = reshape( idx, size(C) ); %// reshape
figure; imagesc( imseg );colormap( cmp ); %// that's it!
```

---

PS,
It is best [not to use `i` as a variable name in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14790740/1714410).